# Xamarin Studio + Xamarin.iOS: how do you set a breakpoint in C or C++ (not F# or C#)?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Running Xamarin Studio 4.1.9, Xamarin.iOS.

When you've linked native code into your application, how do you set breakpoints in that native code?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use a native debugger (e.g. `gdb` or `lldb`) to attach to an existing process, e.g. using `--pid=XXXXX`. Then you can set breakpoints, break/continue execution, set watches... just like you would do with the managed debugger.

This works even if you're debugging the managed side using the managed debugger (inside Xamarin.Studio) but you have to switch back and forth debuggers (e.g. when a breakpoint is hit).

Note: You can use the native debuggers *as-is* (command-line) or from some GUI (e.g. Xcode).